# Variable CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I have layout like this:

[image]

sometimes my layout might look like this (without `menu`):

[image]

sometimes like this (without `sidebar`):

[image]

and finally my layout might transform into this (without `menu` and `sidebar`):

[image]

I use CSS Grid layout, and when a block is missing, empty areas appear.
How to remove this empty areas?

https://codepen.io/perevezencev/pen/ywRrEz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `grid-column`/`grid-row` to place your elements instead of areas like below:

```css
div, aside, main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 75px auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 260px 1fr;

}

.header {
  display: contents;
}

.menu {
  grid-column:1/-1;
  grid-row:2;
  min-height:75px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column:1 / -2;
}

.main{
  grid-column:1 / -1;
}
/*when there is a sidebar "main" will take only the last column*/
.sidebar ~ .main{
  grid-column:2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="brand">brand</div>
    <div class="appbar">appbar</div>
  </header>
  <aside class="sidebar">sidebar</aside>
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
  <main class="main">main</main>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="layout">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="brand">brand</div>
    <div class="appbar">appbar</div>
  </header>
  <aside class="sidebar">sidebar</aside>
  <main class="main">main</main>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="layout">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="brand">brand</div>
    <div class="appbar">appbar</div>
  </header>
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
  <main class="main">main</main>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="layout">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="brand">brand</div>
    <div class="appbar">appbar</div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">main</main>
</div>
```